# Ruby on Rails モデルのエラー表示が日本語にならない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsを勉強中です。scaffoldでフォームを作成し、モデル名のエラー表示を日本語化させたいのですが、
「Addressを入力してください」「Contentを入力してください」
という表示でうまくできません。

解決策を教えていただければと思います。

ja.yml

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      post: 投稿
  attributes:
      post:
  address: メールアドレス
  content: 問い合わせ内容
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

**追記 10/23**
インデントはPythonと同じように重要なんですね。
ja.ymlを以下のようにしたらできました。

```
ja:
  attributes:
    address: メールアドレス
    content: 問い合わせ内容
```

ymlの書き方がイマイチ、ピンッときていないのですが、フォームの場合は、上記のような形で決まり文句として覚えるしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: このymlですが、実際に使用されているソースコードとインデントも含めて全く同じでしょうか？

Comment: ja.ymlは全く同じです。様々な書き方を試しましたが、ダメでした。

Answer (score 2):

ymlはインデント量で構造を表すので、インデント量を以下の通りに修正してみてください。

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      post: 投稿
    attributes:
      post:
        address: メールアドレス
        content: 問い合わせ内容
```

このように書けば`address`や`content`は`ja.activerecord.attributes.post`の配下の値となります。フォームのエラーメッセージはそこを見に行きます。

なお`i18n`は、値の定義がyml内に見つからない場合は、htmlにヒントを出力するようになっています。
「Addressを入力してください」「Contentを入力してください」の要素をブラウザのインスペクタで確認すると分かると思います。